# Maximum surface inside a triangle

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry, computational-geometry

I have encountered the following interesting problem while preparing for a 
contest.

You have a triangle with sides of length `a, b, c` and a rope of length `L`. You need to find
the surfaced enclosed by the rope that has the maximum surface area and it has to be entirely inside the triangle.

So, if `L = a + b + c`, then it's the area of the triangle.

Else, we know that the circle has the biggest surface to perimeter area, so if `L` is smaller  or equal to the perimeter of the inscribed circle of the triangle, then the area will be the area of the circle of perimeter `L.`

So, the remaining case is  `alfa  < L < a + b + c`, where `alfa` is the perimeter of the inscribed circle .

Any ideas would be great!

`EDIT`: I would like to know if I should focus on some kind of algorithm for solving this
or trying to figure it out a mathematical formula. The contest contains somehow a combination of both. The edges can be as long as 100 and the precision of `a,b,c,L` is of 4 digits after the decimal point .

Comment: I would say you actually have three remaining cases, where the inscribed circle is bounded/cut-off by one, two, or three sides of the triangle (but L still less than the perimeter of the triangle).

Comment: i assume you can't cut the rope (to make a second circle) ?

Comment: @TonyMorris I was thinking that if L is larger than the perimeter of the inscribed circle, then we could take that length and then create smaller circles in the remaining gaps, but I am not sure if that is optimal.

Comment: @coredump , yes i was waiting for this response :) , so know i am at the same point : how to prove that it is optimal (or not) to take the remaining rope and create smaller circles, if it is the problem is getting easier.

Comment: I'm guessing the ropes infinitesimally thin? As @MarkPing was saying, you basically start at the inscribed circle and "push" the rope outward till you get the optimal size. I may be wrong but I believe you try to get it the 3 arcs to a point where their da/dr  would be the same, this would technically hold true for the  L > a+b+c be true since the change in area would approach 0 as the arcs reach the corners.

Comment: @SGM1 Yes it is. I think I will accept this answer. Just waiting to see if a better variant exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

..answering my own comment/question, it can be proved that the radii must be equal,

Here is a useful formula:

[image]

the gray area A is

```
A = r^2 ( alpha - Pi + 2/tan(alpha/2) ) /2
```

but even more useful..the arc length is simply:

```
s = 2 ( b - A/r )
```

from here it is straightforward to show the three radii must be equal to each other:

writing the rope length and enclosed area:

```
ropelength = trianglelength  - 2  Sum[r[i]  a[i]  ]
ropearea = trianglearea -  Sum[r[i]^2  a[i] /2 ]
```

where

```
 a[i]=( alpha[i] - Pi + 2/tan(alpha[i]/2) )
```

after a bit of manipulation maximizing the area leads to all r[i] equal. Note the three a[i], ropelength,trainglearea,trianglelength are all constants that you do not need to work out.  Pedantically solve for `r[l] = f( constants, r[2],r[3] )` sub into the second expression and solve for
 `d ropearea /d r[2] = 0` and `d /d r[3] = 0` with the result:

```
r =(1/2) (triangle_length - rope_length) /(Sum(1/tan(alpha[i]/2)) - Pi)
```

(the messy expression for a[i] is substituted only at the last step ) finally..

```
ropearea = trianglearea - (trianglelength-ropelength)^2/(8 Sum[a[i])
     = trianglearea - (1/2)(trianglelength-ropelength)  r
```

edit -- a useful identity ..with a,b,c, the lengths of the sides.

```
Sum(1/tan(alpha[i]/2))  = Sqrt( S^3 / ((S-a)(S-b)(S-c)) )
S = 1/2 (a+b+c)   ! S is semiperimeter not to be confused with arc length s
```

the above expressions then can be used to reproduce the formula for an inscribed circle,

```
 rinscribed = Sqrt( ((S-a)(S-b)(S-c))  / S )
```

Comment: I will try to get some test cases soon. I have to try before I can accept the answer.

Comment: I've written up a python solution implementing my answer below, and it **does** converge the same radius on all corners, but I'm missing something about your answer here.  I'll have to go over it and see if I can figure out what I'm missing.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot follow you (please correct me, if I am wrong): The area of the 4-angle in your drawing is twice the area of the rectangular triangle with sides b, r, and the bisector of alpha, i.e. A+s=2*1/2*b*r; so A+s=b*r. Further tan(alpha/2)=r/b. So b=r/tan(alpha/2). Further s=r^2*(pi-alpha). Thus A=r^2*(alpha-pi+1/tan(alpha/2)), and not A = r^2 ( alpha - Pi + 2/tan(alpha/2) ) /2, as in your answer.

Comment: You say „after a bit of manipulation minimizing the area leads to all r[i] equal". But this is to my mind the difficult part! How did you minimize the area, and how follows that all r[i] are equal? This was exactly the open question, and I cannot see how you did answer this question. Could you please explain?

Comment: consider alpha=pi/2, .. b=r .. A = r^2 (1-Pi/4) .. s=Pi r /2. I will add a bit to the maximim area problem. (should say max not min anyway)

Answer (score 3):

Since a circle has the largest Area/Perimeter, start with the [inscribed circle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incircle_and_excircles_of_a_triangle).  If L is less than that circumference, then shrink appropriately.  If L is longer, grow whichever of the 3 arcs maximizes dA/dL.  I don't know if there's a closed form, but the largest arc will be in the 3rd of the triangle with the sides most approaching parallel.

It should be trivial to solve this algorithmically.  With 4 decimals of precision, increment by 0.0001 checking each arc to see which has the greatest dA/dL for that single increment.

I worked up a drawing of the geometry overnight:
[image: Triangle with incircle]
The inscribed circle is constructed by bisecting each of the angles and finding the intersections of the bisectors.  I've labeled the half-angle "a1" (and all related variables have '1').  The area of the non-circular portion is two trapezoids (one denoted with the red outline).  We can calculate the area for a single trapezoid as L1 * (m1 + R)/2 (note that when L1, L2, L3 are all zero, these trapezoids are all zero, and we just get the inscribed circle area).  The circular cap has a radius of m1 to remain tangent with the side of the triangle.  For a given choice of L1, m1 = R(x1-L1)/x1.

From here you can easily calculate the perimeter and area of each of the three sectors and solve numerically.

I cannot **prove** that this is the largest area, just that this is how to calculate the area and perimeter of this construction.

Comment: I am wondering about the running time, but +1 for the idea :) .

Comment: My rep is too low to add a comment to the question, but 2 circles don't maximize A/L.  Consider two circles -- now draw tangents between the two circles (so you have an capsule-kind of thing).  Keep the tangents but delete the arcs for the two circles, and you've both increased the area and decreased the perimeter.

Comment: i think you are on the right track, but you will end up growing all three sides in some ratio. Prooving the result will be though though.

Answer (score 3):

After reading the answers to this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4808/why-circle-encloses-largest-area, I agree with n.m., and think the optimal curve verifies:

- Curvature is either constant, or flat when it touches the triangle, meaning it is composed of segments lying on the triangle sides, and circle arcs, all sharing the same radius.
- There are no angles, meaning the arcs are tangent to the triangle sides.

With these conditions, the solution is obtained by three circles of same radius R, each tangent to two sides of the triangle (see below).  When R varies between 0 and the radius of the inscribed circle, we start from the triangle itself, and end to the inscribed circle, where all three circles coincide. The length of the curve is the perimeter of the circle of radius R + the perimeter (p) of the smaller triangle: L = 2*Pi*R + p. The area is the area (a) of the smaller triangle + one disc of radius R + the remaining rectangles: A = Pi*R^2 + p*R + a.

[image: The described supposed solution]

Comment: how do we know the radii are equal? It seems right and probably is, but how do you prove it?

Answer (score 2):

If the perimeter of the rope is too small or too large, the answers are trivial. The interesting case is a shape with 6 vertices that goes line-arc-line-arc-line-arc. The arc are all tangent to their neighbouring lines and their radii are equal. I don't have a rigorous proof, but imagine a 2D balloon filled with air and squeezed between the sides of the triangle.

It is easy to express the overall shape and thus the perimeter given the radius; the opposite direction (perimeter to radius) is then easily found numerically.

Comment: I think this is it.. I'm not sure the radii need to be the same though.  If you specify tangent arcs with 3 radii (@  each corner) that will uniquely determine the length and area. After a bunch of trig its a straightforward optimisation problem in just 3 unknowns.